# Which permissions do I need in order to send someone else / root files?

Tags: permissions, email

So I was playing a little with permissions in my system and then I noticed  there is no permission specified for sending the file somewhere else.

I tried, as a simple user, the following command:
`mail -a //etc/shadow myAddress@domain.com`
I was satisfied to get a `Permission Denied` message, but it's still not clear what the permissions are required in order to send a file.

I mean, I use the `mail` command for mail protocol, but what about other commands or other protocols?

btw, the permissions for the `shadow` file were:

```
-rw-r-----   1 root  shadow    1759 Oct 23  2017 shadow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one, because "sending" a file isn't really a filesystem-level operation. What the `mail` command does, is that it opens the file for reading, reads the data, and sends (writes) it over the network socket (probably encoded in the case of email, not that it matters). Similarly, an FTP client, `scp`, or any other would do the same, they'd read the file as usual.

You don't have read access to `/etc/shadow`, so `mail` running with your user id cannot open it for reading.

Linux does have the [`sendfile()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html), which directly copies data between two file descriptors, but that's basically the same as calling `read()` on the one and `write()` on the other fd, except that it happens within the kernel so there's less system call overhead. It, too, requires the source to be opened for reading.

Comment: So you claim I can send a file **if and only if** I got reading permissions?

Comment: @ZENir That is correct.  You have to be able to read a file in order to send it.